# How to use mssqllocaldb in Entity Framework Core 1.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How to using the localdb directly with Entity Framework Core? I found many demo is just for asp.net core. But not for console or unittest direct.

Demo code :

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();

    var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
}
```

My code :

```
_fixture.SqlConnectionStr=@"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DailyDbContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

var connection = new SqlConnection(_fixture.SqlConnectionStr);
connection.Open();

// Create the schema in the database
using (var context = new DailyDbContext(options))
{
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

Throws an exception as follows:

Stack:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at HQF.Tutorials.EntityFrameworkCore.XUnitTest.UnitTest1.Test1() in 

 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. 指定的 LocalDB 实例名称无效。
```

But sqlite works just fine:

```
 // In-memory database only exists while the connection is open
 var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");

 var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DailyDbContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)                   
                .Options;

            // Create the schema in the database
            using (var context = new DailyDbContext(options))
            {
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            }
```

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://www.michael-whelan.net/sql-server-localdb-2014-connection-string/) that describes one common problem with connection strings for SqlLocalDb: http://www.michael-whelan.net/sql-server-localdb-2014-connection-string/   Depending on the version of SqlLocalDb the connection string must be slightly different. This may or may not be your problem -- but it is very easy to try out anyway.

Comment: You have a typo in the connection string here `Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb`. When using verbatim strings you should not double `"\"`.

Comment: @lvan Stoev it will throw exception ` System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot open database "daily_db_Test" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'FRANK-PC\Frank'.`

Comment: @IvanStoev is correct. The exception you are seeing above is because your connection string is incorrect. After updating string as Ivan suggested you got log in failure error because your database does not exist and you called connection.Open() on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that is working right.

```
public SimpleIntegrationTest()
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MonsterContext>();

    builder.UseSqlServer($"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=monsters_db_{Guid.NewGuid()};Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
            .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

    _context = new MonsterContext(builder.Options);
    _context.Database.Migrate();

}
```

Comment: Please explain the crucial part of your solution to make it more valuable for future readers.

Comment: @GertArnold yeah, I Will found more detail about that.